# Does Android Studio use Gradle Daemon?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-daemon

I used Gradle Daemon to build Android project from the command line and noticed it was quite fast. But Android Studio seems a bit slow compared to the command line, so that got me wondering: Is Android Studio using Gradle Daemon to speed up builds or is something else that's slowing them?

Answer (score 3):

Create a file with the name **"`gradle.properties`"** in the following directory:

```
- /home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
- /user/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
- %USERPROFILE%\.gradle (Windows)
```

And inside of it, you have to add this line:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Furthermore, you can add the following line to improve the speed a little:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

> You have more information on **[speed-up-gradle](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/)**.

Comment: My question is does AndStu use GradDae by default ? Or should I use what you said ?

Comment: This works for me, and it goes fast.

Comment: Did this speed up your gadle?

Comment: I was already doing this. What I wanted to know is [copy paste above]

Comment: Don't get you @Mehdiway

Comment: What @Mehdiway was trying to ask was does Android Studio enable the gradle daemon by default. On Gradle documentation it says that some IDEs may this already enabled. Does Android Studio have it enabled? : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html#sec:embedding_daemon